# What command to use to zoom out a plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I have a barplot and the names for the bars are all vertical on the x-axis. However, the names are fairly long and don't show completely in the plot. Is there any command I can use to zoom out the plot? I have already tried the package "zoom" and zm() but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to handle this is to increase the margin size before plotting.   Here is a simple example.  First, to show the problem:

```
LongNames = c("RatherLongName_1", "RatherLongName_2",
            "RatherLongName_3", "RatherLongName_4") 
barplot(1:4, names.arg=LongNames, las=3)
```

[image: Unadjusted barplot]

Then with the margins adjusted.

```
par(mar=c(10,4,4,2))
barplot(1:4, names.arg=LongNames, las=3)
```

[image: Adjusted Margins]